# Google direction API returning incorrect value for TrafficModel

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3

According to google API documentation all traffic model should have different values but I am getting the same values for BEST_GUESS,PESSIMISTIC,OPTIMISTIC.

I am using below code

```
//Source address
$a = 'Los Angeles International Airport, 1 World Way, Los Angeles, CA 90045, United States'; 
//Destination address
$b = 'Beverly Wilshire, Beverly Hills (A Four Seasons Hotel), 9500 Wilshire Boulevard, Beverly Hills, CA 90212, United
        States';
//Pass source and destination address in google map API for PESSIMISTIC
$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin='. urlencode($a).'&destination='. urlencode($b).'&departure_time=1451491810&travelMode=google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING&drivingOptions=trafficModel:google.maps.TrafficModel.PESSIMISTIC&key=AIzaSyC7h7m5bRs-BZwk0XTXEQTB74dZujeLzZs';
//output:  duration_in_traffic = 50 mins

//Pass source and destination address in google map API for OPTIMISTIC
$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin='. urlencode($a).'&destination='. urlencode($b).'&departure_time=1451491810&travelMode=google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING&drivingOptions=trafficModel:google.maps.TrafficModel.OPTIMISTIC&key=AIzaSyC7h7m5bRs-BZwk0XTXEQTB74dZujeLzZs';
//output:  duration_in_traffic = 50 mins

//Pass source and destination address in google map API for BEST_GUESS
$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin='. urlencode($a).'&destination='. urlencode($b).'&departure_time=1451491810&travelMode=google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING&drivingOptions=trafficModel:google.maps.TrafficModel.BEST_GUESS&key=AIzaSyC7h7m5bRs-BZwk0XTXEQTB74dZujeLzZs';
    //output:  duration_in_traffic = 50 mins
```

**Update:**

I am using

//departure_time = 04-january-2016 //1451898000

```
$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin='. urlencode($a).'&destination='. urlencode($b).'&departure_time=1451898000&mode=driving&traffic_model=pessimistic&key=AIzaSyC7h7m5bRs-BZwk0XTXEQTB74dZujeLzZs';

//Output

pessimistic==>>
duration_in_traffic => 31 mins

optimistic==>
duration_in_traffic => 25 mins

best_guess==>
duration_in_traffic => 25 mins

Above responses are not correct as per the live google map

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Los+Angeles+International+Airport,+1+World+Way,+Los+Angeles,+CA+90045,+United+States/Beverly+Hills,+CA/@34.0077875,-118.4878535,12z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m17!4m16!1m5!1m1!1s0x80c2b0d213b24fb5:0x77a87b57698badf1!2m2!1d-118.40853!2d33.9415889!1m5!1m1!1s0x80c2bc04d6d147ab:0xd6c7c379fd081ed1!2m2!1d-118.4003563!2d34.0736204!2m3!6e0!7e2!8j1451898000
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're partially using the parameters for  the Javascript-API, but you must use parameters for [the webservice](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro?hl=de#RequestParameters).

1.

```
    travelMode=google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
```

should be

```
    mode=driving
```

(you may omit it, it's the default)

2.

```
 drivingOptions=trafficModel:google.maps.TrafficModel.[value]
```

must be

```
 traffic_model=[value]
```

where `[value]` may be  `best_guess`, `optimistic` or `pessimistic`

---

So the `$url` should e.g. be

```
$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin='. urlencode($a).'&destination='. urlencode($b).'&departure_time=1451491810&mode=driving&traffic_model=pessimistic&key=AIzaSyC7h7m5bRs-BZwk0XTXEQTB74dZujeLzZs';
```

[pessimistic](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Los%20Angeles%20International%20Airport,%201%20World%20Way,%20Los%20Angeles,%20CA%2090045,%20United%20States&destination=Beverly%20Wilshire,%20Beverly%20Hills%20(A%20Four%20Seasons%20Hotel),%209500%20Wilshire%20Boulevard,%20Beverly%20Hills,%20CA%2090212,%20United%20States&departure_time=1451491810&mode=driving&traffic_model=pessimistic&key=API_key) duration_in_traffic = 1 hour 19 mins

[optimistic](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Los%20Angeles%20International%20Airport,%201%20World%20Way,%20Los%20Angeles,%20CA%2090045,%20United%20States&destination=Beverly%20Wilshire,%20Beverly%20Hills%20(A%20Four%20Seasons%20Hotel),%209500%20Wilshire%20Boulevard,%20Beverly%20Hills,%20CA%2090212,%20United%20States&departure_time=1451491810&mode=driving&traffic_model=optimistic&key=API_key) duration_in_traffic = 28 mins

[best_guess](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Los%20Angeles%20International%20Airport,%201%20World%20Way,%20Los%20Angeles,%20CA%2090045,%20United%20States&destination=Beverly%20Wilshire,%20Beverly%20Hills%20(A%20Four%20Seasons%20Hotel),%209500%20Wilshire%20Boulevard,%20Beverly%20Hills,%20CA%2090212,%20United%20States&departure_time=1451491810&mode=driving&traffic_model=best_guess&key=API_key) duration_in_traffic = 50 mins

Comment: Can we pass somehow pessimistic,optimistic and best_guess in a single call of google API and can return response for pessimistic,optimistic and best_guess in same call?

Comment: afaik currently it's not possible

Comment: Ok, did you check my updated code? I am taking the date of January 2016 but its not responding correctly.